# Equals betwen two graphs fail..how come?

Tags: jgrapht

I tried to simply equals two jgraphT instances and it returns false, even though they are identical.
I then tried to override the equals with an implementation of mine:

```
public boolean equals(MyGraph<CustomV, CustomE> otherGraph){
    boolean result = true;

    Iterator<CustomV> vertexes = otherGraph.vertexSet().iterator();
    while(result && vertexes.hasNext()){
        result = this.containsVertex((V) vertexes.next());  
    }

    Iterator<CustomE> edges = otherGraph.edgeSet().iterator();
    while(result && edges.hasNext())
        result = this.containsEdge((E) edges.next());


    return result;
}
```

and saw that the containsEdge() method fails if that edge is not the EXACT object. This is strange as I made sure to override the equals methods of both edges and switches...

edit: 
made this experiment:

```
CustomV aNode = new CustomV(1,2);
myGraph.addVertex(aNode);
System.out.println(myGraph.containsVertex(aNode)); //true
System.out.println(myGraph.containsVertex(new CustomV(1,2))); //false..but should be true
```

and as you can see the containsVertex() method does not seem working..

edit2:
Thanks to silly freak I almost solved: I had to override hashcode() method too.
Now, this worked for Vertexes but for edges I get a null pointer exception on the hashcode, this is my overridden method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return (getSource().hashCode()+getTarget().hashcode());
}
```

I get a null pointer when I try to create an edge on a graph (I suppose hashcode() is called here):

```
myGraph.addEdge(a,b);
```

Problem is that getSource() and getTarget() seem to return null when called in that moment...how to solve?
This is the exception stack:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.at.network.types.CustomE.hashCode(CustomE.java:71)
>       at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:366)
>       at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:466)
>       at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:453)
>       at org.jgrapht.graph.AbstractBaseGraph.containsEdge(AbstractBaseGraph.java:359)
>       at org.jgrapht.graph.AbstractBaseGraph.addEdge(AbstractBaseGraph.java:208)
>       at org.jgrapht.graph.GraphDelegator.addEdge(GraphDelegator.java:131)
>       at org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultListenableGraph.addEdge(DefaultListenableGraph.java:162)
>       at org.at.network.types.MyGraph.addCustomEdge(MyGraph.java:27)
>       at org.at.network.Test.main(Test.java:220)

The addcustomedge method is the following:

```
public CustomE addCustomEdge(V sourceVertex, Port sourcePort, 
        V targetVertex, Port targetPort){
    CustomE l = (CustomE)super.addEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
    l.setSourceP(sourcePort);
    l.setTargetP(targetPort);

    return l;
}
```

Port is just a simple datastructure for a couple of strings.

Comment: please show us your your hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: also, you have some other issues: suppose `this` has edges `{e1, e2}` and `other` has `{e2}`. your loop would not realize `e1` is missing from `this`. easiest is to check the number of edges (and vertices) too.

Comment: Equals methods just compare internal attributes pair of the two objects...I didn't overwrite hashcode()

Comment: Silly Freak thanks for feedback. Anyway something still does not work as I tried to compare two exactly identical graphs and I got a "false" as answer...

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point it out. have you looked at the javadoc for `Object.equals` and `hashCode`? make sure you understand it, and you will have your answer.

Comment: I know what I am talking about and it's not the first time I override the equals method...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java  "Whenever `a.equals(b)`, then `a.hashCode()` must be same as `b.hashCode()`" that's especially relevant when using a HashSet, as you probably do in `edgeSet()`. I also know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry you were right :) I still have another problem (edited question, anyway if you answer me I'll mark it as correct)

Comment: if you post a stack trace of the NPE, it would be easier, though I'm pretty sure what the problem is

Comment: oh, and your `CustomE` constructor is important, too.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the intial problem: [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

> Whenever a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode()

that's especially relevant when using hash based data structures, as elements are put in buckets according to their hash codes, and only those in the same bucket are compared using `equals()`.

---

`myGraph.addEdge(a,b);` implicitly creates the edge using an `EdgeFactory` (presumably a `ClassBasedEdgeFactory`). Look at lines 206 and following in [`AbstractBaseGraph`](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/AbstractBaseGraph.java#L206), where the exception is coming from:

```
E e = edgeFactory.createEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);

if (containsEdge(e)) { // this restriction should stay!
```

As you said yourself, you use a default constructor to construct the edge (by the way, you don't even seem to set the vertexes at all):

```
CustomE l = (CustomE)super.addEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
l.setSourceP(sourcePort);
l.setTargetP(targetPort);
```

that means, at the time the edge is used by `containsEdge`, it is not fully initialized! Generally, before exposing an object to code you don't have absolute control over, it should be initialized. You have just experienced one of many problems that can come up when you expose uninitialized objects. In particular, as source and target are still `null` when `containsEdge` performs a hash-based lookup, this code:

```
(getSource() == null? 0:getSource().hashCode())
```

throws a `NullPointerException`.

The fix to the problem is to fully initialize the edge before passing it to the JGraphT API. As you not only set source and target vertex but also port, it seems that the `EdgeFactory.createEdge()` does not have enough information to do so. Luckily, there seems to be an overloaded method [`Graph.addEdge(V sourceVertex, V targetVertex, E e)`](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/Graph.java#L159). I would advise you to use it like this:

```
public CustomE addCustomEdge(V sourceVertex, Port sourcePort, 
        V targetVertex, Port targetPort){
    CustomE l = new CustomE(sourceVertex, sourcePort, targetVertex, targetPort);
    boolean added = addEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex, l);
    if(added) return l;
    else return null;
}
```

of course you first have to create that `CustomE` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, and how to make sure that source and target are set? Any ideas? I also though to simply make hashcode() return a constant...would it be wrong?

Comment: You're showing way too little code to say that. as I said in a comment to the question, I need at least the stack trace of your null pointer exception, and the CustomE contructor.

Comment: No constructor is defined at all so it is called the default one. I edited the main question showing the stack trace.

Comment: Then I can't help you. The question has some uses for future viewers, regarding `equals` and proper initialization of objects, but adding to it further will degrade it slowly to something not useful to anyone but you. I suggest that you debug your code (search the internet on how to debug java in your IDE) and make sure that the vertexes of your `CustomE` are initialized before `hashCode` is called.